# Proper runtime executable install location

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I thought I'd ask for official clarification here because I've seen conflicting information from different sources. Until recently, I understood that we should be placing node executables under `lib/${PROJECT_NAME}` via the `RUNTIME` category of the CMake `install` command. This seems like the only place `ros2 run` and `ros2 launch` find them.

However, after doing some Windows development, I discovered shared libraries (`.dll`s) have to go under `bin/` in the install space, and they also fall under the `RUNTIME` category. This is also recommended by the current [ament_cmake documentation](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Ament-CMake-Documentation/#id5).

So what is the proper thing to do here? Is everything shifting to being installed under `bin/` and the `ros2` commands need to be updated to see those files? Or is the expectation now that executable and library targets should always be installed with separate `install()` commands into the two different places?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367854/proper-runtime-executable-install-location/) by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 971 on 2020-12-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The recommended best practice is still to have your executables in `lib/${PROJECT_NAME}`, so as to not pollute the PATH and to reduce the chances of file collisions from different packages.

Your second guess it what I think you need to do, have separate `install()` commands for libraries and executables. I don't think we have any good examples of packages that have both executables and libraries in them, but we have examples of packages that install executables and others that install libraries, e.g.:

- https://github.com/ros2/examples/blob/869e303254182c48bc3bf8dff6c34e17a1b87d90/rclcpp/topics/minimal_publisher/CMakeLists.txt#L26-L31
- https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/febe86e6b5a35e77da228426ad718ec2be06a902/rclcpp/CMakeLists.txt#L197-L202

Also, when using the install statement that the ament documentation suggests (the one you linked to) it will handle installing `.dll` files to `bin` for you, placing the `.lib` files in `lib` instead. So you shouldn't need to do anything else for Windows.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2020-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on 2020-12-18**:
Thanks for explaining the rationale. I'll probably switch to a style of a separate `install` command per target now, since I always sort-of felt that would be cleaner way of organizing the CMake code anyways.